# Python searching for reversed Tuples in a set

Tags: python, set, tuples

If I have

```
Set = {(0,1), (1,1), (1,0)}
```

How can I determine whether or not (a,b) *and* (b, a) are present in the set?

That is the Set above would return True and this set:

```
Set = {(0,1), (1,1), (1,2), (1,0)} #missing (2,1)
```

would return false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
all(tup[::-1] in Set for tup in Set)
```

For each element of the set, we require that the reversal of that element is in the set. The above code is a pretty literal translation of that problem definition into Python.

Comment: `{1, 2}
  File "C:/Users/Tristan/PycharmProjects/pythontut.py", line 67, in <module>
{(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)}
    b = all(tup[::-1] in Set for tup in Set)
  File "C:/Users/Tristan/PycharmProjects/pythontut.py", line 67, in <genexpr>
    b = all(tup[::-1] in Set for tup in Set)
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: I'm getting those errors when I try your solution. Any tips?

Comment: @Coder117: Your set isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Whoops I was using the wrong name. Thank you for your help! Might I ask another question here?

Comment: @Coder117: Not in the comments. If you want to ask another question, that's what the Ask Question button is for. Make sure it stands on its own without requiring people to read this question first.

Comment: Ok thank you apparently there is a time limit on asking questions so I will ask in about an hour. Thanks so much for your help!